# How to get only id from url

Tags: php, url

I have thousands of urls which have ids i want to get only ids from url for example
This is my array

```
Array
(
    [0] => http://www.videoweed.es/file/f62f2bc536bad
    [1] => http://www.movshare.net/video/5966fcb2605b9
    [2] => http://www.nowvideo.sx/video/524aaacbd6614
    [3] => http://vodlocker.com/pbz4sr6elxmo
)
```

I want ids from above links

**f62f2bc536bad**

**5966fcb2605b9**

**524aaacbd6614**

**pbz4sr6elxmo**

I have use `parse_url` function but its return me `path` which include all things after slash(/) like **/file/pbz4sr6elxmo**

```
<?php 
foreach($alllinks as $url){
  $parse = parse_url($url);
  echo $parse['path'];
}
?>
```

**Output**

> /pbz4sr6elxmo
>
> /video/5966fcb2605b9
>
> /file/f62f2bc536bad
>
> /video/524aaacbd6614

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can try with `explode` -

```
$alllinks = array
(
    'http://www.videoweed.es/file/f62f2bc536bad',
    'http://www.movshare.net/video/5966fcb2605b9',
    'http://www.nowvideo.sx/video/524aaacbd6614',
    'http://vodlocker.com/pbz4sr6elxmo'
);

foreach($alllinks as $url){
  $temp = explode('/', $url);
  echo $temp[count($temp) - 1].'<br/>';
}
```

**Output**

```
f62f2bc536bad
5966fcb2605b9
524aaacbd6614
pbz4sr6elxmo
```

> This will only help if the the `url` structure is same, i.e. the last part is the `id`

Comment: @bos3 i have one issue you know that i have alot of links which i want only ids and you give answer very well i am very thankfull of you i have many links like that http://vidzi.tv/233sdfsfsdf.html in last there is .html what should i do to get only ids from this type of link? please help

Comment: Do the same and the use `str_replace('.html', '', $var);`

Answer (score 3):

If the URLs always ends with the id you can simply do

```
$url = 'http://www.videoweed.es/file/f62f2bc536bad';
$url_split = explode('/', $url);
$code = $url_split[count($url_split) - 1];
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
$alllinks = array(
    'http://www.videoweed.es/file/f62f2bc536bad',
    'http://www.movshare.net/video/5966fcb2605b9',
    'http://www.nowvideo.sx/video/524aaacbd6614',
    'http://vodlocker.com/pbz4sr6elxmo'
);

foreach($alllinks as $url){
  $parts = explode('/', $url);
  echo end($parts).'<br/>';
}
```